# Php absolute path is not working with glob function

Tags: php, rendering, glob, absolute-path

I am trying to render all images from a specific folder but blank images are showing. How to give correct absolute path of folder to render only specific type images. The exact same number of pictures are rendering in the browser from the local folder but all images are blank.

[image: Output]

```
<?php
ini_get("include_path"));
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$dirname = ($root . "/folder/assets/img/post/cards/");
/img/post/cards/');
$images = glob($dirname . "*.png");
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 padd-10">
            <div class="posters text-center">
                <a href="image-editor.php?image_path=' . $image . '">
                    <img src="' . $image . '" >
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="poster-actions">
                <a href="./assets/img/post/Bright-Happy-Birthday.png" download target="_blank">Download</a>
                <a href="image-editor.php?image_path= ' . $image . '">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: That is invalid code after setting `$dirname`.

Comment: Path for the images needs to be relative to the DocumentRoot. Try removing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from the resulting images.

Comment: @brombeer images didn't render if i removed it.

Comment: Inspect one of the img elements and make sure its path is indeed the correct path. For your `glob` images, there is a folder named `folder/` in the path, which seems to be missing in `./assets/img/post/Bright-Happy-Birthday.png` - is this image displayed correct?

Comment: @brombeer, yes image displayed correctly because its a static link. I want to make all images dynamic so that if any user clicks on edit, he can edit the image. Relative path works fine and also displays images but relative path wont works if i click on edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might approach this slightly different. To modify yours, I would do a couple things:

1. Create a config file, of sorts, in your domain root where you define important elements like directory paths

**/var/www/html/folder/config.php**

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
# Set the root here which, in this instance, would write:
# /var/www/html/folder
define('DOMAIN_ROOT', __DIR__);
# Set your assets folder when called in browser
define('MEDIA_ASSETS', '/assets');
# Set your image folder when called in browser
define('MEDIA_IMAGES', MEDIA_ASSETS.'/img');
```

2. Now in the file you are building with your image gallery you will want to include this config:

**/var/www/html/folder/whatever-this-is-called.php**

```
<?php
# Include the config
include_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
ini_get("include_path"));

# Real path to the file
$filePath = DOMAIN_ROOT.str_replace('/', DS, MEDIA_IMAGES).DS.'post'.DS.'cards';
# Browser view file path
$domainPath = MEDIA_IMAGES.'/post/cards';
# Fetch files
$images = glob($filePath . "*.png");
# Loop over the found files
foreach($images as $image):
    # Store the file name
    $fname = basename($image); ?>

<div class="col-lg-4 padd-10">
    <div class="posters text-center">
        <a href="image-editor.php?image_path=<?php echo $path = base64_encode($images) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $dpath = "{$domainPath}/{$fname}" ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="poster-actions">
        <a href="<?php echo $dpath ?>" download target="_blank">Download</a>
        <a href="image-editor.php?image_path=<?php echo $path ?>">Edit</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach;
```

Another approach would be to save these file names to a database for easy fetch and and validation and all that. With what you have, you have to be careful you validate the path being sent to `image-editor.php` to make sure someone isn't able to edit unintended files/images on your system.

> Note, I have not tested this, but there are enough notes there to see what is trying to be accomplished.